# Redis streams and multi/exec(transaction) in Redis Cluster

Tags: redis, transactions, stream, cluster-computing

I want to publish a message to the Redis stream as part of Redis transaction(multi/exec). In a clustered environment, all data that is part of a redis transaction must be in same shard, so the question is how can I control in what shard is message written.

For other type of data I use hash tags in keys like so: `hset foo{123} mykey myval`

I could use hash tag in stream name like so: `xadd mystream:{123} * mykey myval`, but how would I consume messages from multiple streams in single consumer, especially if hashtag is for example account number, an there can be 1 mil account in redis = stream for each account =  1 mil streams ?

Answer (score 0):

> but how would I consume messages from multiple streams in single consumer,

XREAD/XREADGROUP command supports multiple keys as argument, and you can consume multiple streams in a single consumer. However, you must ensure all these keys located on the same slot.

> especially if hashtag is for example account number, an there can be 1 mil account in redis = stream for each account = 1 mil streams ?

You'd better not use account number as hashtag. Instead, you can split these account number into groups, use group number as hashtag, and consume multiple streams in the same group with a single consumer.

For example, using modulus operator to do the split: `hashtag = account-number % group-number`